# Chiral anomaly of Weyl fermion is half of Dirac

Tags: path-integral, quantum-anomalies, chirality

How can one mathematically see that the anomaly for a Weyl fermion is half of Dirac in the Fujikawa path integral method?

**Edit**

I do understand that a Dirac fermion is two Weyl fermions. What I wish to understand is - how is this taken into account when calculating the phase change in the measure under a chiral transformation. When writing down the path integral for a Weyl fermion all we do is put a $$P_+$$
in the action. What about the measure?

Comment: Because a Dirac fermion is two Weyl fermions?

Comment: I do understand that. What I wish to understand is - how is this taken into account when calculating the phase change in the measure. When writing down the path integral for a Weyl fermion all we do is put a $$P_{+}$$ in the action. What about the measure?